# Button not working after updating the WordPress page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have this field:
[image]

There're 0 problems with functionality, unless i update the page and try to click on the settings
[image]

It cannot be opened, no idea why.Here's how the element is builded

```
<i class="fa fa-cog pull-right dx-setting-column js-setting-column" title="Element Setting"></i>
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: Open up the developer dools (f12 if you use chrome) and go to the console tab. Are there any errors here? It sounds like a javascript issue

Comment: I've opened it and 0 errors or warnings

Comment: There may be an ajax issue. What is the name of the composer you are using that provides that layout? I presume you're in the backend?